# AMD processor to an Intel processor

Tags: cpu, motherboard, upgrade

I've got an AMD FX 8320 as CPU and I wanted to upgrade it to an Intel i7 4790k. I just don't know if the CPU will fit in the motherboard I have now. The AMD fits. [This is my motherboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTfzw.jpg) Will the Intel i7 4790k CPU fit in this motherboard?
[image]

Comment: Rule of thumb? This will NEVER work on a recent (post 486 I guess) processor. For AMD match sockets (and AMD keeps sockets a whole), Intel tends to keep socket types for 2 generations unless they have a transitional generation when they can't keep their cadence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer has a [760GA-P43 (FX)](https://www.msi.com/product/motherboard/760GA-P43-FX.html#hero-overview) motherboard.

**[760GA-P43 (FX) specifications](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-MSI/760GA-P43_%28FX%29.html)**

- 760GA-P43 (FX) motherboard
- AMD 760G+SB710 Chipset
- CPU socket type: AM3+ Socket

**AM3+ Socket supported processors**

- AMD Phenom II
- AMD Athlon II
- AMD FX
- AMD Sempron - [list of supported AMD Sempron models](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-MSI/760GA-P43_%28FX%29.html#cs)
- AMD Opteron 3000 Series

The Intel i7 4790k will not fit in this motherboard. The Intel i7-4790K needs Intel's 1150 socket.

Comment: You should note that *AM3+* is AMD's own socket. The i7-4790K needs Intel's 1150 socket.